# How to set href to a checkbox on click?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

1.How to set href to a checkbox on click

```
<a href="/Demo/sense/show/4">
  <input type="checkbox" />Yes
</a>

  <a href="/Demo/sense/list">
      <input type="checkbox" />NO
    </a>
```

But when i checked a checkbox.. it not going to another page..

2.how to set checked on click on **YES** text rather than **Yes Checkbox**
Please Help me..
Thanx

Comment: Why would you want this? it will go to another page

Comment: yup.. on checkbox checked.. i want to render to another page

Comment: remember check boxes are suposed to do what they do, if the user doesn't expect a redirect its strange. You can do a button instead. Check boxes are for `<form>` submiting.

Comment: Answer for Q2 - simple. Make use of the `<label>` tag. You just wrap the check-box and text you'd like associated ('Yes' in your case), then, either the label or the check-box may be clicked to toggle the checkbox. I.e `<label><input type='checkbox'/>Yes</label>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<input type="checkbox"  onclick='window.location.assign("/Demo/sense/show/4")'/>Yes`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
<input id="cb" type="checkbox" onchange="window.location.href='http://google.com/'">
```

And then maybe a label for it too:

```
<label for="cb">Yes</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your code simple:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />Yes
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" />NO

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#chk1').click(function(){
          window.location='http://www.yahoo.com'; // link of your desired page.  
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Not especially helpful in this context. Op was not seeking a jQuery solution.