# Passing Check Box Value in PHP by using ahref tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a  php flie that connects the database and selects the table login_info  and retries the login details like email ,name,row id and level and with the result  I have shown a table having a check box and I want to  pass check box value by  href tag.
Below given code:

```
 <?php

    include("../script/config.php");

    $sql = "select * from login_info";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

         $username=$row['username'];

         $useremail=$row['useremail'];

         $level=$row['level'];

         $id=$row['id'];

     <tr>

       <td class="style3"><div align="left" class="style9 style5">
      <div align="center"><strong><?php echo $username;  ?></strong></div>
        </div>      
      </td>
      <td class="style3"><div align="left" class="style9 style5"><div align="center"><strong><?php echo $useremail;  ?></strong></div></div>
      </td>
      <td class="style3"><div align="left" class="style9 style5">
                    <div align="center">
                      <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"  value="1"  
                       <?php 
                      if ($level==1)
                      {
                      echo 'checked' ;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                       echo 'unchecked';
                      }
                      ?>

                      />
                 </div>
                  </div>
       </td>
       <td class="style3"><div align="left" class="style9 style5">
         <div align="center"><strong>
         <a href="../script/Edit_user.php?Id=<?php echo $id;?>&checkbox=<?php echo $checkbox;?>">
        <img src="../images/update.jpg" width="42" height="40" u="image" /></a></strong></div>
           </div>
           </td>



    ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand... Need more information, details about what you want... This is not clear at all...

Comment: You need to do it by javascript or jquery to change href on clicking the check box. I think that would answer your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269069/how-to-set-href-to-a-checkbox-on-click

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and then use it as you like.

```
$isChecked = ($level == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');

<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"  value="1" <?php echo $isChecked; ?>/>
<a href="../script/Edit_user.php?Id=<?php echo $id;?>&checkbox=<?php echo $isChecked;?>">
```